# Fastest Server Setup to reach blockchain?

Tags: server-side

Is there an ideal place to set up my server to reach the blockchain faster? Not sure the best place and what factors to consider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a provider like [QuickNode](https://www.quicknode.com/) might benefit you. As [QuickNode](https://www.quicknode.com/) has a global network of nodes with automatic DNS routing and load balancing, it ensures you connect to the best and nearest node automatically. This gives you the freedom to set up your server at the location of your choice.

You can also read this [article to get more information on how latency is measured and what affects latency.](https://blog.quicknode.com/justifying-quick-in-quicknode-response-time-comparison-of-various-blockchain-node-providers/)